# Using external javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on JavaScript and PHP lately and I was wondering whether I could return a value from an external JavaScript function into a php file.

My code is:

webpage.php

```
<title>Place Your order</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js">
        var boolean = validateForm();
</script>
```

validation.js:

```
if(namevalidation(name)){
        if(emailvalidation(email)){
            if(addressvalidation(address)){
                if(cityvalidation(city)){
                    if(statevalidation(state)){
                        if(zipvalidation(zip)){
                            if(creditvalidation(Credit)){
                                if(monthvalidation(Month)){
                                    if(yearvalidation(year)){
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to get the value `true` from my validation.js to the boolean in webpage.php. Will this work? or what should I do to get the return value from this external function?

Comment: That's a ninja code... `:D`

Comment: looks like the pyramid of doom, to me.  Oh, yea its called AJAX

Comment: php runs on server....javascript runs in browser long after php has completed it's job. Not really clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Is there a reason why you nest ifs inside each other instead of using the or operator of ||?

Comment: Capitals, removed "Hey"

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the external Javascript and when on the page's lifecycle you want it to run?

If it is in the client side during execution, you just invoke the script with its url and load it with the page, in another scenario i'd say be careful with the fact that php runs *before* javascript, since it's run by the server, (most of the time) compiles into a webpage, and goes to the client, and that's where JS lives.

And please please please, refactor that validation into a single `if` sentence, use a boolean variable, concatenate AND's, I don't know.

Comment: This is a form validation script so it runs on the onclick function of a form button

Comment: If your javascript is validating a form *before* `webpage.php`, then you could pass a variable in a `GET` or `POST` string; but it would be absolutely meaningless because you still couldn't trust the user input.  Validation *must* be done in PHP also; the javascript validation is just a courtesy to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that all your Javascripts will get executed eventually. For example if you try this:

```
if(namevalidation(name)){
        window.isValid = false;
        if(emailvalidation(email)){
            if(addressvalidation(address)){
                if(cityvalidation(city)){
                    if(statevalidation(state)){
                        if(zipvalidation(zip)){
                            if(creditvalidation(Credit)){
                                if(monthvalidation(Month)){
                                    if(yearvalidation(year)){
                                        return (window.isValid = true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then you will have your value inside a variable `isValid`, which will be reachable from anywhere. However, you might want to avoid global scope, I used the global scope here with the sole intention to demonstrate is dynamics.